# querySelector for all of same type - Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have an app drawer that I am animating with the entry labels appearing after the drawer is toggled.

However, I cannot get the JS to select all of the  elements containing the labels.

I have even tried to give them all the same ID and using 'querySelector', 'querySelectorAll', 'this.$.' and 'this.$$.'

Can anybody help?

**HTML**

```
<paper-icon-item>
   <iron-icon icon="home" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="spantext">Home</span>
</paper-icon-item>
<paper-icon-item>
   <iron-icon icon="done" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="">Expert</span>
</paper-icon-item>
<paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="search" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="">Search</span>
</paper-icon-item>
<paper-icon-item>
    <iron-icon icon="supervisor-account" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="">Admin</span>
</paper-icon-item>
     <div class="flex"></div> <!-- THIS IS THE ONLY WAY THAT I COULD GET THE LAST ENTRY TO BE FLEXED TO THE BOTTOM -->
 <paper-icon-item>
     <iron-icon icon="settings" slot="item-icon"></iron-icon> <span id="">Settings</span>
 </paper-icon-item>
```

**JS**

```
toggleMenu : function() {
        var menu = this.$.drawer;
        var avatar = this.$.avatar;
        var userData = this.$.userDetails;
        var spanText = this.$.spantext; /* THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING STUCK */

        menu.classList.toggle('drawerExpand');
        avatar.classList.toggle('userAvatarResize');
        userData.classList.toggle('userDetailsReveal');
        spanText.classList.toggle('revealSpan');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `querySelectorAll('paper-icon-item iron-icon ~ span')`?

Comment: This hasn't worked either.
It's fine though, I've found another way around it instead which means I don't have to use this function.

Thanks anyway.